# Magento - move Categories block to top of sidebar (right)

Tags: xml, magento, categories, static-block

I'm not too familiar with Magento, but i've done a lot with code before and modifying themes and plugins in Wordpress ... but i'm out of idea's on this one.

I'm want to get the block that display's the Categories on the top of its sidebar (right sidebar) indicated by the red border around the element with the arrow pointing to the position i want to place it to.

Any help on the matter would be much appreciated.

[Link to the website/page](http://www.materiaalservice.nl/verhuur/koningsdag.html)

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */

Supported layout update handles (action):
- catalog_product_gallery
- catalog_product_compare_index

Supported layout update handles (special):
- default
- catalog_category_default
- catalog_category_layered
- catalog_product_view

-->
<layout version="0.1.0">

<!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->

    <default>

        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="cms/block" name="left.permanent.callout">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>left_column_block</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="cms/block" name="right.contact">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>contact</block_id></action>
            </block>
            <!-- <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/> -->
            <block type="cms/block" name="right.permanent.callout">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>right_column_block</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="footer_links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog" ifconfig="catalog/seo/site_map"><label>Site Map</label><url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" /><title>Site Map</title></action>
        </reference>
        <block type="catalog/product_price_template" name="catalog_product_price_template" />
    </default>


<!--
Category default layout
-->

    <catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>        
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.rightnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                        <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                        <!--
                            <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>9</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        -->
                    </block>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>

<!--
Category layered navigation layout
-->

    <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>        
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.rightnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                    <!-- <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/su.phtml</template></action> -->
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                        <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                        <!--
                            <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>3</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>3</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>9</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        -->
                    </block>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>

<!--
Compare products page
-->

    <catalog_product_compare_index translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product Compare List</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/popup.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/scriptaculous.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_compare_list" name="catalog.compare.list" template="catalog/product/compare/list.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_compare_index>

    <customer_account_index>
        <reference name="right">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_index>

<!--
Product view
-->

    <catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>

            <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
                <!--
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/summary.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>short</type><template>review/helper/summary_short.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>...</type><template>...</template></action>
                -->
                <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
                    <label>Alert Urls</label>
                </block>

                <action method="setTierPriceTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml</template></action>

                <block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
                <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" translate="label">
                    <label>Product View Extra Hint</label>
                </block>

                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
                    <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
                    <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml"/>
                    <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
                </block>
                        <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml" translate="label">
                    <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
                    <action method="insert"><block>product.tierprices</block></action>
                    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml"/>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.addto</block></action>
                </block>

                <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
                    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
                    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
                </block>
                <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
                    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
                    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
                </block>
                <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container1</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
                <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container2</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
            </block>
                            <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
                    <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
                    <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
                </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" after="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
        </reference>        
    </catalog_product_view>

<!--
Additional block dependant on product type
-->
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple translate="label" module="catalog">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Simple)</label>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.simple.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                    <label>Product Extra Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable translate="label" module="catalog">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Configurable)</label>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.configurable" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.configurable.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                    <label>Product Extra Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped translate="label" module="catalog">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Grouped)</label>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_grouped" name="product.info.grouped" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.grouped.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                    <label>Product Extra Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual translate="label" module="catalog">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Virtual)</label>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_virtual" name="product.info.virtual" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.virtual.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                    <label>Product Extra Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual>



<!--
Product send to friend
-->

    <catalog_product_send translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product Email to a Friend</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_send" name="product.send" template="catalog/product/send.phtml">
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_send>

<!--
Product additional images gallery popup
-->

    <catalog_product_gallery translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product Image Gallery Popup</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/popup.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_gallery" name="catalog_product_gallery" template="catalog/product/gallery.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_gallery>

<!--
SEO Site Map
-->

    <catalog_seo_sitemap translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Seo Sitemap (Common)</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="page/template_container" name="seo.sitemap.container" template="catalog/seo/sitemap/container.phtml">
                <block type="page/template_links" name="seo.sitemap.links" as="links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
                <block type="page/html_pager" name="seo.sitemap.pager.top" as="pager_top" template="page/html/pager.phtml"/>
                <block type="page/html_pager" name="seo.sitemap.pager.bottom" as="pager_bottom" template="page/html/pager.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_seo_sitemap>

    <catalog_seo_sitemap_category translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Seo Sitemap (Category List)</label>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="catalog"><title>Site Map</title></action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="catalog_seo_sitemap" />
        <reference name="seo.sitemap.container">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="catalog"><title>Categories</title></action>
            <block type="catalog/seo_sitemap_category" name="seo.sitemap.sitemap" as="sitemap" after="pager_top" template="catalog/seo/sitemap.phtml">
                <action method="bindPager"><pager>seo.sitemap.pager.top</pager></action>
                <action method="bindPager"><pager>seo.sitemap.pager.bottom</pager></action>
                <action method="setItemsTitle" translate="title" module="catalog"><title>categories</title></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="seo.sitemap.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog"><label>Products Sitemap</label><url helper="catalog/map/getProductUrl"/><title>Products Sitemap</title></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_seo_sitemap_category>

    <catalog_seo_sitemap_category_tree translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Seo Sitemap (Category Tree)</label>
        <reference name="seo.sitemap.container">
            <remove name="seo.sitemap.pager.top" />
            <remove name="seo.sitemap.pager.bottom" />
            <block type="catalog/seo_sitemap_tree_pager" name="seo.sitemap.tree.pager.top" as="pager_top" template="page/html/pager.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/seo_sitemap_tree_pager" name="seo.sitemap.tree.pager.bottom" as="pager_bottom" template="page/html/pager.phtml"/>
            <remove name="seo.sitemap.sitemap" />
            <block type="catalog/seo_sitemap_tree_category" name="seo.sitemap.sitemap_tree" as="sitemap" after="pager_top" template="catalog/seo/tree.phtml">
                <action method="bindPager"><pager>seo.sitemap.tree.pager.top</pager></action>
                <action method="bindPager"><pager>seo.sitemap.tree.pager.bottom</pager></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_seo_sitemap_category_tree>

    <catalog_seo_sitemap_product translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Seo Sitemap (Product List)</label>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="catalog"><title>Site Map</title></action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="catalog_seo_sitemap" />
        <reference name="seo.sitemap.container">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="catalog"><title>Products</title></action>
            <block type="catalog/seo_sitemap_product" name="seo.sitemap.sitemap" as="sitemap" after="pager_top" template="catalog/seo/sitemap.phtml">
                <action method="bindPager"><pager>seo.sitemap.pager.top</pager></action>
                <action method="bindPager"><pager>seo.sitemap.pager.bottom</pager></action>
                <action method="setItemsTitle" translate="title" module="catalog"><title>products</title></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="seo.sitemap.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog"><label>Categories Sitemap</label><url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl"/><title>Categories Sitemap</title></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_seo_sitemap_product>
</layout>
```

Comment: Can you show your existing layout XML updates?

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry, i'm a Magento noob :S

Comment: Please, go to your custom theme folder (for example, app/design/frontend/custom/theme/). And then open layout/ folder. Find there files catalog.xml and local.xml (if exists). And attach the content of the files.

Comment: There is no local.xml but there is a catalog.xml. Just tried to edit my post and paste but Stackoverflow won't let me save the post after pasting in the code for some reason :S
EDIT: Just managed to update the post with the catalog.xml code.